# Unable to add DataRow to DataSet

Tags: sql, vb.net

---

UPDATE

---

I have put this in a Try Catch and also tried the code below, and I get an Exception and the Exception Message states, "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CUsers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." I'm not trying to insert anything into the the Identity Column. I have it set to auto increment.

Not sure what to do.

```
CUsersTableAdapter.Fill(MasterDataSet.CUsers)

Dim AddRow As MasterDataSet.CUsersRow
AddRow = MasterDataSet.CUsers.NewCUsersRow

AddRow.UserFirst = "Test"
AddRow.UserLast = "Testing"
AddRow.UserEmail = "Test@Email.com"
AddRow.UserPhone = "555-555-5555"
AddRow.UserWorkCenter = 482126468
AddRow.UserRole = 908977894
AddRow.MergeID = 739809237

MasterDataSet.CUsers.Rows.Add(AddRow)

CUsersTableAdapter.Update(MasterDataSet.CUsers)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add `DataRow` to `DataSet`, but you can add It to any of the table inside the DataSet, so Do something like :

```
Dim newRow As DataRow= MasterDataSet.Tables(0).NewRow()
newRow.UserFirst = "Test"
newRow.UserLast = "Testing"
newRow.UserEmail = "Test@Email.com"
newRow.UserPhone = "555-555-5555"
newRow.UserWorkCenter = 482126468
newRow.UserRole = 908977894
newRow.MergeID = 739809237
MasterDataSet.Tables(0).AddRows(newRow)
```

Comment: I am trying this now, but why does the code I provided work with other DataSources that aren't created in Visual Studio? If I add a DataSource from an SQL Server Database, or an Access Database, the code I provided works flawlessly.

Comment: I was able to implement this and I put it in a Try Catch and the Exceptions says "Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'CUsers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF." I'm not trying to insert anything into the the Identity Column. I have it set to auto increment.

Answer (score 0):

```
MasterDataSet.Tables(0).AddRows(newRow)
```

Comment: Please add more description to the answer.

Comment: While this code may resolve the poster's issue, a few lines of explanation would help everyone who reads this post to understand the solution.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.